# how to find next and previous date from date variable

Tags: java

Trying to solve a problem puzzle but not having much luck.

I have a list of dates and a Date object that get passed through to a function:

```
function void dateSorting(List<Date> dateList, Date newDate);
```

Based on the newDate i need to find out between which 2 indexes of list would this newDate fit into.

so e.g.

if date is 1/3/2015 and list contains:

```
INDEX, VALUE
0    , 5/1/2015
1    , 20/2/2015
2    , 15/3/2015
3    , 11/4/2015
```

Then function would print out/return 1 and 2 and the corresponding dates 20/2/2015 & 15/3/2015.

I have been scouring the net for pseudocode and examples but no luck. Closest i came to is closest date to newDate which doesn't help me.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Ok, I think that you should post your code what you have tried.

Comment: And what about newDate is **1/1/2015**? I means, what should result.

Comment: 1/1/2015 should not print out previous but only following, i don't have working code, I have not managed to get anywhere near with this problem.

Comment: btw java has no keyword `function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I got one for you.

```
void dateSorting(List<Date> dateList, Date newDate) {

    for (int i = 0; i < dateList.size(); i++) {
        if (newDate.before(dateList.get(i))) {
            if (i != 0)
                System.out.println("Previous index:" + (i - 1));
            System.out.println("Next index:" + i);
            break;
        } else if (i == dateList.size() - 1) {
            System.out.println("Previous index:" + i);
        }
    }
}
```

And I tested my code like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

    List<Date> dateList = new ArrayList<Date>();

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    dateList.add(sdf.parse("5/1/2015"));
    dateList.add(sdf.parse("20/2/2015"));
    dateList.add(sdf.parse("15/3/2015"));
    dateList.add(sdf.parse("11/4/2015"));

    System.out.println("Testing with 1/3/2015.");

    dateSorting(dateList, sdf.parse("1/3/2015"));

    System.out.println("Testing with 1/1/2015.");

    dateSorting(dateList, sdf.parse("1/1/2015"));

    System.out.println("Testing with 12/4/2015.");

    dateSorting(dateList, sdf.parse("12/4/2015"));

}
```

And I got the following result:

```
Testing with 1/3/2015.
Previous index:1
Next index:2

Testing with 1/1/2015.
Next index:0

Testing with 12/4/2015.
Previous index:3
```

I believe this will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Replace *17/11/2015* with `Date.toString()` (date iterator)

```
public static void main(String []args){
    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    try {
        date = sdf.parse("17/11/2015");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);
        System.out.println(cal.getTime());
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        System.out.println(cal.getTime());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

These References will help you
[Ref 1](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-date-and-calendar-examples/)
[Ref 2](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-compare-dates-in-java/)

Answer (score 0):

try something like below code:

```
    long current = newDate.getTime();
    boolean flag = false;
    for (int i =1; i < dateList.size(); i++){
       long a = dateList.get(i-1).getTime(); long b = dateList.get(i).getTime();

       if ( (a > current && b < current) || (a < current && b > current){
          //newDate is in between index i-1 and i, set flag to true and do your stuff.
        }

       if(!flag) {  //newDate did not fit between any indexes. 
       }
    }
```

You should understand Calendar and Date APIs. It is preferable to use Calender API as most methods in Date are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you really expected:

**First you have to crate a class implementing Comparator to sort your Date list :**

```
public class DateSort implements Comparator<Date> {

@Override
public int compare(Date d1, Date d2) {
    return (d1.getTime() > d2.getTime() ? 1 : -1);
}

 }
```

**Then you can get implement an algorithm to get closet max date and closest min date like below:**

```
public class CompareDate {

    public void compare(String oparation, List<Date> dateList, SimpleDateFormat sdf, Comparator<Date> comparator)
            throws ParseException {

        Collections.sort(dateList, comparator);
        //using joda time api
        DateTime givenDate = new DateTime(sdf.parse("01/03/2015"));
        Days diff = Days.days(0);
        OUTER:
        for (Date date : dateList) {
            Days newDiff = Days.daysBetween(new DateTime(date), givenDate);
            switch (oparation) {
                case "max-closet":
                    if (newDiff.getDays() < diff.getDays()) {
                        diff = newDiff;
                        System.out.println(oparation + " - " + sdf.format(date));
                        break OUTER;
                    }
                    break;
                case "min-closet":
                    if (newDiff.getDays() > diff.getDays()) {
                        diff = newDiff;
                        System.out.println(oparation + " - " + sdf.format(date));
                        break OUTER;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        List<Date> dateList = new ArrayList<>();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        dateList.add(sdf.parse("05/01/2015"));
        dateList.add(sdf.parse("20/02/2015"));
        dateList.add(sdf.parse("15/03/2015"));
        dateList.add(sdf.parse("11/04/2015"));
        new CompareDate().compare("max-closet", dateList, sdf, new DateSort());
        new CompareDate().compare("min-closet", dateList, sdf, new DateSort().reversed());
       //I m reversing the date list so I can sort dates to descending order. 
    }
}
```

Here I have used [joda time api](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/joda/joda-time-2.3.jar.zip) to get the different between two dates.